# How to add an olText UserProperty to an email

Tags: outlook

I am trying to add a UserProperty to an email using  win32com.
The UserPropertyType should be set to 'olText'.

For the record, the name of the UserProperty ('NewDomain') is already a member of the collection of Outlook UserProperties.

I have tried the following:

```
import win32com.client as w32c
outlook=w32c.Dispatch('Outlook.Application').GetNameSpace('MAPI')
inbox=outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
emails=inbox.Items
email=emails.GetLast()
email.UserProperties.Add("NewDomain",UserPropertyType='olText',True)
```

I got the following error:
TypeError: Add() got an unexpected keyword argument 'OlUserPropertyType'

The code works well in VBA with the syntax:
email.UserProperties.Add("NewDomain", olText, True)

Many thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UserPropertyType argument is an enum (int), not a string. olText is 1, so your code must be

```
email.UserProperties.Add("NewDomain", 1, True)
```